# iOS Firebase sort and limit - observer not called

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

This is my data model.

```
project-foo
 -posts
   -KLs123412341234
     key: "-KLs123412341234"
     message: "free cupcakes"
     time: 1467675688163
   -...
     key: "..."
     message: "..."
     time: ...
```

I'd like to only fetch posts in the last 15 minutes.
I see in my Firebase Console children being added, but the problem is that the observer doesn't seem to be invoked - `"hello"` is not printed.

My iOS app has the following code, which **does not** get invoked:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var ref: FIRDatabaseReference?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
        ref!.queryOrderedByChild("time")
            .queryStartingAtValue(startTime())
            .observeEventType(.ChildAdded, withBlock: { snapshot in
            print("hello")
        })

    }
}
```

My Android app has the following code, which **does** get invoked:

```
Query query = mDatabase.orderByChild("time").startAt((double)startTime());
query.addChildEventListener(new PostListener(this, mMap));

class PostListener implements ChildEventListener {
    public PostListener(Context context, GoogleMap map) {
        ...
    }

    @Override
    public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
        Log.i(TAG, "hello");
        ...
    }
}
```

**Update**:
My mistake was not realizing that I had initialized `mDatabase` (in the android version) with path `posts`. The fix was simply to initialize `ref` with `FIRDatabase.database().referenceWithPath("posts")` instead of `FIRDatabase.database().reference()`.

Comment: What does startTime() look like?

Comment: I tested with just setting it to zero and it didn't help.

Comment: What is ref?...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For JSON structure,:-

```
"posts" : {
  "autoID1" : {
    "key" : "autoID1",
    "timestamp" : 101
  },
  "autoID2" : {
    "key" : "autoID2",
    "timestamp" : 102
  },
  "autoID3" : {
    "key" : "autoID3",
    "timestamp" : 103
  },
  "autoID4" : {
    "key" : "autoID4",
    "timestamp" : 104
  },
  "autoID5" : {
    "key" : "autoID5",
    "timestamp" : 105
  },
  "autoID6" : {
    "key" : "autoID6",
    "timestamp" : 106
  },
  "autoID7" : {
    "key" : "autoID7",
    "timestamp" : 107
  }
}
```

Use this code:-

```
  FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("posts").queryOrderedByChild( "timestamp").queryStartingAtValue(101).queryEndingAtValue(103).observeEvenType(.Value, with: { (snap) in
        if let snapDict = snap.value as? [String:AnyObject]{

            for each in snapDict{

                print(each.value)

            }
          }
        }, withCancel: {(err) in


    })
```

Make sure your security rules are allowing the user to retrieve `posts` value's

Using **`.ChildAdded`** only gets called when a child node is added to that Database node. Using **`.Value`** will retrieve you entire Data whose timestamp is between those value's

Now most likely you cannot get the Timestamp value from  **`FIRServerValue.timestamp()`** as it's just a command sent to the firebase server to add the timestamp at that particular node.

So instead use a custom timestamp to store your timestamp, and for the end value just add 15 min to that timestamp.

Read this [Manipulate NSDate](http://nshipster.com/nscalendar-additions/)